# checking a list for how many times an integer appears with user input in python3

Tags: python, python-3.x, list

Hello I am new to python and am trying to work out a way where I can get a list of integers from a user , then a single integer from a user , then check how many times this integer appears in the list of integers. so far i have :

```
list1 = int(input("how hany items are in your list?"))

list2= []

for i in range(list1):
    
    list_item = input("enter your list of numbers")    
    list2.append(list_item)


checker1 = int(input("enter a number to check if its in your list"))

checker2 = list2.count(checker1)

print("numbers of items your integer appears in the is is" +  checker2 + "times" )
```

this is as far as i could get but cant get the code to work. I know that in the print statement you can't concatenate a sting and an integer but I dont now how to go about making this work as i am new. any help would be great! thank you

Comment: “Can’t get the code to work” - you need to be a __lot__ more specific about what this means. If you get an error message, edit __the full text__ of it into your question __as text__

Comment: Hint: the first time you accept input, you're storing strings. The second time you're not.

Answer (score 0):

You have to do 2 things to solve this problem.
First:
In your for loop, you don't cast the input to an int. You did do that in the first input though. Given that input() returns a string, you have to cast it to an int, otherwise you can't compare them the way you do right now. Furthermore, you should replace the '+'s with commas. Concatenating strings is achieved with commas in python. Result should look something like this:

```
list1 = int(input("how hany items are in your list?"))

list2 = []

for i in range(list1):
    list_item = int(input("enter your list of numbers"))
    list2.append(list_item)

checker1 = int(input("enter a number to check if its in your list"))
checker2 = list2.count(checker1)

print("numbers of items your integer appears in the is is", checker2, "times")
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use **F strings** feature in python

```
list1 = int(input("how hany items are in your list?"))
list2= []
for i in range(list1):
    list_item = input("enter your list of numbers")    
    list2.append(list_item)


checker1 = int(input("enter a number to check if its in your list"))
checker2 = list2.count(checker1)
print(f"numbers of items your integer appears in the is is {checker2} times" )
```

Use `f""` strings and whenever you want to add a variable then enclose it with `{}` within the string quotes.